# json con datos de tablas relacionadas

Tags: jquery, laravel, json

hola a todos como estan? gente una consultilla que me trae loco, tengo que obtener a un json datos
de tablas vinculadas, mediante una funcion en mi controlador puedo obtener los datos de la variable $asignacion, pero no de detalle....

En mi controlador con esta linea puedo obtener los datos de la variable $asignacion:

```
 $asignacion = AsignacionMaterial::all()->where('tecnico_id','=',$id);
```

pero esta otra variable no se como obtenerla (ambas tablas estan vinculadas):

`$detalle = DetAsignacionMaterial::all()->where(????);`

las relaciones en los modelos las tengo definidas asi:

Modelo AsignacionMaterial:

```
 public function detasignacionmaterial(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\DetAsignacionMaterial','asignacion_material_id','id');
    }
```

y en el modelo DetAsignacionMaterial asi:

```
  public function asignacionmaterial(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\AsignacionMaterial', 'asignacion_material_id', 'id');
   }
```

y la funcion con la que estoy intentando en el controlador es asi:

```
public function getMaterialTecnico($id){
        //$tecnico = Tecnico::with('tecnicos')->findOrFail($id);
        //$det="";
        $asignacion = AsignacionMaterial::all()->where('tecnico_id','=',$id);
        //$det= AsignacionMaterial::select('id')->where('tecnico_id','=',$id);
        $detalle = DetAsignacionMaterial::all()->where('asignacion_material_id','=','asignacion_material_id=id');
        return response()->json([
            'dato' => array(
                //'tecnico' => $tecnico,
                'asignacion' => $asignacion,
                'detalle' => $detalle
            )        ], 200);
    }
```

Actualmente solo puedo obtener los datos de la asignacion, pero no los del detalle y Lo que necesito es que mediante un id pueda traer los datos de una asignacion, asi como el detalle de la misma...

Saludos a todos y gracias por cualquier comentario

Comment: Por medio de las relaciones de Eloquent es simple, añade si las tienes definidas y explica mas a detalle la salida que buscas obtener

Comment: @BetaM hola añadi el codigo que manejo hasta ahora

Comment: Las relaciones que definiste entre los 2 modelos no son correctas, ¿por que una relación hasMany se vincula con otra por medio de belongsToMany? cuando la primera es de uno a muchos y la otra de muchos a muchos?

Comment: una asignacion puede tener mas de un detalle,

Comment: Entonces debería ser hasMany

Comment: las cambie pero aun asi no me trae los datos del detalle